# What is the (expected) outcome of this hybrid auction?

Tags: game-theory, economics

1. A certain hybrid auction can be accurately modelled as follows.
2. There are $n$ risk-neutral, rational participants $i=1,2,\ldots,n$, and a guy called Zerro: $i=0$.
3. Each, except Zerro, has a private value of the good (only known to themselves) $v_i\sim_\mathrm{i.i.d.} \mathrm{UNIF}(0,1)$.
4. An English auction (EA) is held. Zerro is allowed to, and does, open the bid at $0$. The participants then start bidding (*or not*). The EA results in a highest bid $B_\mathrm{EA}$ by $i_\mathrm{EA}$. *However, no participant actually gets the auctioned good and no participant has to pay.*
5. Then a Dutch auction (DA) is held. The starting price is $1$. All participants, including $i_\mathrm{EA}\ne 0$ (if he exists), can take part. (And all remember what happened during the EA.) If the price happens to reach $B_\mathrm{EA}$ then $i_\mathrm{EA}$ has won. The winner is denoted by $i_\mathrm{DA}$ and his price is denoted by $B_\mathrm{DA}$. The winner gets the good and has to pay.
6. This is a one-time affair. All participants come from different universes and will leave afterwards back to those universes.
7. All of the above, as well as this line, is common knowledge to the participants.

**Question: What are the (possible) values of $B_\mathrm{EA}$ and $B_\mathrm{DA}$?**

I'm hoping for either expectation values or specific values given $v_i, i=1,\ldots,n$.

*This question is hopefully related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301484/how-can-the-observed-strategies-in-this-actual-auction-be-explained). That is my original question, but an answer to this, more theoretical, question could possibly add some background truth(s).*

Comment: It doesn't seem like there is any value in anybody engaging in the EA - it provides no additional value and can only provide information to others.

Comment: @Gugg If you know the [Revenue Equivalence Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auction_theory#Revenue_equivalence) of Auction Theory, it seems like the auction house is trying to generate more revenue by making participants violate the assumptions. For example, your valuation of the house will rise, if you know that someone else values it more. In this case, the valuation bids are actually dependent (and not independent), and should be interpreted more of a signal coming from a true distribution instead.

Comment: @OP What do you mean by "values"? Are you looking for the social choice function this auction implements by, say, Bayesian Nash equilibrium?

Comment: @Michael I am looking for all equilibrium values/outcomes $B_\mathrm{EA}$ and $B_\mathrm{DA}$ as functions of $n$ and $v_i,i=1,\ldots,n$. The crux, I believe, is whether all $B_\mathrm{EA}>0$ can be rigorously shown to be out of (any) equilibrium.

Comment: @Gugg In the first round, it doesn't matter what auction scheme you specify, correct? (All the agents are doing in the first round is announcing a bid, nothing is binding.)

Comment: @Michael Any highest bid in the first round will be binding if it stands up in the second round. So, if there is no bid in the second round, the first round's highest bidder has to pay up and gets the good.